# how to insert formula in excel using vba

Tags: excel

How to insert the formula for the entire column using vba

Answer (score 6):

like this?

this is for relative notation RC

```
Columns("N:N").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[1],RC[2])"
```

Edit:

you could also use this notation (absolute) :

```
Columns("M:M").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B3)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i am facing another problem ,In my sheet i am insert the formula in the cell at the range G5 from G5 onwards i want to auto fill the formula in the entire column  it is possible ?

Comment: Tried to paste this function but i get a runtime error..?  .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(C2;4);LEFT(A2;3);RIGHT(B2;3))"